# Vectorization to achieve performance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I want to avoid using for loop in the following code to achieve performance. Is vectorization suitable for this kind of problem?

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],
              [5,6,7,8,9],
              [0,1,2,3,4],
              [5,6,7,8,9],
              [0,1,2,3,4]],dtype= np.float32)

temp_a = np.copy(a)

for i in range(1,a.shape[0]-1):
    for j in range(1,a.shape[1]-1):
        if a[i,j] > 3:
            temp_a[i+1,j] += a[i,j] / 5.
            temp_a[i-1,j] += a[i,j] / 5.
            temp_a[i,j+1] += a[i,j] / 5.
            temp_a[i,j-1] += a[i,j] / 5.
            temp_a[i,j]   -= a[i,j] * 4. / 5.
a = np.copy(temp_a)
```

Comment: As long as you run it on all the fields, `generic_filter` at the end would modify all data

Comment: I haven't come across such pre defined filter.But it is not hard to create one as we want. So if you give us an example how your array elements has to be modified by the filter, we could build one.

Comment: @Saranns I'll prepare an example and update my question.

Comment: As it stands the result appears to depend on the order in which elemens are updated. Is that intentional?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I changed the example by using a temporary array.  I guess if I use a predefined filter function the results would not be dependent on the order in which elements are updated, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically doing convolution, with some special treatment for borders.

Try the following:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d


# define your filter
f = np.array([[0.0, 0.2, 0.0],
              [0.2,-0.8, 0.2],
              [0.0, 0.2, 0.0]])

# select parts of 'a' to be used for convolution
b = (a * (a > 3))[1:-1, 1:-1]

# convolve, padding with zeros ('same' mode)
c = convolve2d(b, f, mode='same')

# add the convolved result to 'a', excluding borders
a[1:-1, 1:-1] += c

# treat the special cases of the borders
a[0, 1:-1] += .2 * b[0, :]
a[-1, 1:-1] += .2 * b[-1, :]
a[1:-1, 0] += .2 * b[:, 0]
a[1:-1, -1] += .2 * b[:, -1]
```

It gives the following result, which is the same as you nested loops.

```
[[  0.    2.2   3.4   4.6   4. ]
 [  6.2   2.6   4.2   3.   10.6]
 [  0.    3.4   4.8   6.2   4. ]
 [  6.2   2.6   4.2   3.   10.6]
 [  0.    2.2   3.4   4.6   4. ]]
```

Comment: This answer uses less memory and is slightly faster than my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My trail uses 3 filters, `rot90`, `np.where`, `np.sum`, and `np.multiply`. I am not sure which way to benchmark is more reasonable. If you **do not** take into account the time to create filters, it is roughly 4 times faster.

```
# Each filter basically does what `op` tries to achieve in a loop

filter1 = np.array([[0, 1 ,0, 0, 0],
                  [1, -4, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) /5.

filter2 = np.array([[0, 0 ,1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, -4, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) /5.
filter3 = np.array([[0, 0 ,0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, -4, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) /5.
# only loop over the center of the matrix, a
center = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`filter1` and `filter2` can be rotated to represent 4 filters individually.

```
filter1_90_rot = np.rot90(filter1, k=1)
filter1_180_rot = np.rot90(filter1, k=2)
filter1_270_rot = np.rot90(filter1, k=3)
filter2_90_rot = np.rot90(filter2, k=1)
filter2_180_rot = np.rot90(filter2, k=2)
filter2_270_rot = np.rot90(filter2, k=3)

# Based on different index from `a` return different filter

filter_dict = {
             (1,1): filter1,
             (3,1): filter1_90_rot,
             (3,3): filter1_180_rot,
             (1,3): filter1_270_rot,
             (1,2): filter2,
             (2,1): filter2_90_rot,
             (3,2): filter2_180_rot,
             (2,3): filter2_270_rot,
             (2,2): filter3
            }
```

Main function

```
def get_new_a(a):
    x, y = np.where(((a > 3) * center) > 0) # find pairs that match the condition
    return a + np.sum(np.multiply(filter_dict[i, j], a[i,j])
                      for (i, j) in zip(x,y))
```

Note: There seem to be some numerical errors such that `np.equal()` would mostly return `False` between my result and OP's while `np.close()` would return true.

#### Timing results

```
def op():
    temp_a = np.copy(a)

    for i in range(1,a.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(1,a.shape[1]-1):
            if a[i,j] > 3:
                temp_a[i+1,j] += a[i,j] / 5.
                temp_a[i-1,j] += a[i,j] / 5.
                temp_a[i,j+1] += a[i,j] / 5.
                temp_a[i,j-1] += a[i,j] / 5.
                temp_a[i,j]   -= a[i,j] * 4. / 5.
    a2 = np.copy(temp_a)   

%timeit op()
167 µs ± 2.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit get_new_a(a):
37.2 µs ± 2.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Note again, we ignore the time to create filter as I think it would be a one time thing. **If you do want to include the time to create filters**, it is roughly two times faster. You might think it is not fair becasue op's method contains two `np.copy`. The bottleneck of op's method, I think, is the for loop.

#### Reference:

[`numpy.multiply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) do a elementwise multiplication between two matrix.
[`np.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) does rotation for us. `k` is a parameter that you can decide how many times to rotate.
[`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) can use this function to check whether two matrices are close within some error that you can define.

Comment: Is this gonna work for larger arrays with different shapes?

Comment: @BehzadJamali I haven't tried. I just used your example for now. If you have other example, I can try to experiment over it.

Comment: I think you just need to define the right filter to tackle different shapes.

Comment: This answer does not work for arrays with different shape (You can test it by just adding another column to array `a`). My real array is 4000*4000 matrix (lets say `a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=6, size=(4000,4000))` ). Is it possible to compare your answer with the one that I provided down here for the big random array?

Comment: Now I see what you mean by a different shape. I am not sure how to do that with (4000, 4000) matrix for now. I think that belongs to another problem. My 2 cents is that you need to pay attention to repetition and make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
a = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,6,2,8,0],
              [0,1,5,3,0],
              [0,6,7,8,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0]],dtype= np.float32)

up= np.zeros_like(a)
down= np.zeros_like(a)
right= np.zeros_like(a)
left = np.zeros_like(a)

def new_a(a,u,r,d,l):

    c = np.copy(a)
    c[c <= 3] = 0

    up[:-2, 1:-1] += c[1:-1,1:-1] / 5.
    down[2:, 1:-1] += c[1:-1,1:-1] / 5.
    left[1:-1, :-2] += c[1:-1,1:-1]/ 5.
    right[1:-1, 2:] += c[1:-1,1:-1] / 5.
    a[1:-1,1:-1] -= c[1:-1,1:-1] * 4. / 5.
    a += up + down + left + right

    return a
```